# Generating Dimension Tables with PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have generated a simple dimension table where the hierarchy goes like

product cd -> product cat cd -> product_class_cd

of course we also need labels for each of the codes.

In order to generate this dimension table I have written the following PIG code

```
// get all unique combinations of product_cd, cat_cd and class_cd
X1 = FOREACH PRODUCT GENERATE PRODUCT_CD, PRODUCT_CAT_CD, PRODUCT_CLASS_CD;
X2 = DISTINCT X1;

// now lookup the labels for codes
X3 = JOIN X2 BY PRODUCT_CD, CODE_VALUE BY CODE_VALUE;
X4 = FOREACH X3 GENERATE PRODUCT_CD, DISPLAY AS PRODUCT_CD_NAME,PRODUCT_CAT_CD, PRODUCT_CLASS_CD;

// now lookup the labels for cat_cd
X5 = JOIN X4 BY PRODUCT_CAT_CD, CODE_VALUE BY CODE_VALUE;
X6 = FOREACH X5 GENERATE PRODUCT_CD, PRODUCT_CD_NAME, PRODUCT_CAT_CD, DISPLAY AS PRODUCT_CAT_NAME, PRODUCT_CLASS_CD;

// now lookup the label for class_cd
X7 = JOIN X6 BY PRODUCT_CLASS_CD, CODE_VALUE BY CODE_VALUE;
DimProduct = FOREACH X7 GENERATE PRODUCT_CD, PRODUCT_CD_NAME, PRODUCT_CAT_CD, PRODUCT_CAT_NAME, PRODUCT_CLASS_CD, DISPLAY AS PRODUCT_CLASS_NAME;

// write out the dimension
DUMP DimProduct;
```

it works and I get a dimension table with 6 columns. but it seems I am writing too much code.

Can I achieve what I want with less lines of code? otherwise as the number of attributes rise in my dimension, this code will become very messy.

I also need to introduce a column called DimProduct_id which is like a line number in my dimension table. How do I do that?

Comment: why are you doing  foreach after each join ? I think no need for that, if you want to see what is the schema of the result add `describe X4`